# When does MAPE (Mean Absolute Percentage Error) fail?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, scikit-learn, numpy, mape

I have a multioutput regression model that predicts float values. When using [MAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error) to evaluate regression model performance (using either built in libraries or implementing a function for it) I am getting very large numbers

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
...
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1)
...
print("Mean Absolute Percentage Error: ", mean_absolute_percentage_error(ytest, model.predict(xtest)))
```

Would give me a very large number:

> Mean Absolute Percentage Error: 43288238481823123

Another implementation would provide me infinity

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred): 
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100

print("Mean Absolute Percentage Error: ", mean_absolute_percentage_error(ytest, model.predict(xtest)))
```

> Mean Absolute Percentage Error:  inf

In the same model the R^2 value of the model would be close to 1.

I am posting this question to ask if MAPE has strong limitations or scenarios that could lead to these results.

I can provide the dataset and multioutput algorithm if needed.

Answer (score 4):

`MAPE` can be problematic ([see this thread for MAPE's shortcomings](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/156678)).

In `scikit-learn`, if one of the values of `y_true` is zero, that will result in an arbitrarily high number.

Another example of that is the following ([Source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html))

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
>>> y_true = [1., 0., 2.4, 7.]
>>> y_pred = [1.2, 0.1, 2.4, 8.]
>>> mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred)
112589990684262.48
```

For additional documentation on scikit-learn's metric MAPE, [go here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error).